# Targeting children of sibling elements

Tags: javascript, html

The following code targets `fieldsets` that are siblings so that those `fieldsets` can be enabled when `input buttons` are selected in the previous one:

```
document.querySelectorAll("fieldset").forEach(fieldset => {
  fieldset.addEventListener("change", function() {
    let nextFieldset = this.nextElementSibling

    while (nextFieldset && !nextFieldset.disabled) {
      nextFieldset = nextFieldset.nextElementSibling
    }

    if (nextFieldset) {
      nextFieldset.disabled = false
    }
  })
})
```

---

```
<form>
  <fieldset> … </fieldset>
  <fieldset> … </fieldset>
  <fieldset> … </fieldset>
</form>
```

> How can I target `fieldsets` that are inside separate `sections`?

```
<form>
  <section><fieldset> … </fieldset></section>
  <section><fieldset> … </fieldset></section>
  <section><fieldset> … </fieldset></section>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full working solution:

```
document.querySelectorAll("section").forEach(section => {
  section.addEventListener("change", function() {
    let nextFieldset = this.nextElementSibling.querySelector("fieldset")

    while (nextFieldset && !nextFieldset.disabled) {
      nextFieldset = nextFieldset.nextElementSibling
    }

    if (nextFieldset) {
      nextFieldset.disabled = false
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for your problem

```
    document.querySelectorAll("fieldset").forEach(fieldset => {
  fieldset.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let nextFieldParent = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
    let nextFieldset = nextFieldParent.firstElementChild;    
    while (nextFieldset && !nextFieldset.disabled) {
      nextFieldParent = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
    nextFieldset = nextFieldParent.firstElementChild;
    }

    if (nextFieldset) {
      nextFieldset.disabled = false
    }
  })
})
```